# How to hide Actionbar customview when drawer opened

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am working in android navigation drawer menu.In this I added customview to Actionbar for showing popup menu.It is working fine.when I close navigation drawer I am showing that custom view.But I open navigation drawer I am trying to hide that custom view.Please help me
code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.customaactionlayout);
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME

                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE

                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.custombutton);

   customSettings=(Button) findViewById(R.id.custombutton);
  customSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

           PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(NavigationActivity.this, customSettings);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());  
            popup.show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can override methods onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) & onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) in ActionBarDrawerTohgle:

```
 mDrawerToggle = new SherlockActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.app_name,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.action_settings  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
```